# How do I pass and extract data in googlemaps api in my android app using java?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I am new to android development but familiar with java. I want to send a request (containing coordinates of locations) to google maps api for distance matrix and later calculate the sum of distances for each point. The response from api is either in javascript or xml (i dont really know which one). How do i send the query in java and how do i extract the distances from the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using seperate classes to send and recieve data through the Google maps API. try using JSON to send aaplication data.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use any thing like this (or that is owned by google etc.. ) You first need to setup a developer account at https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/

It does cost 25 dollars but in all honesty it's worth it as you get access to a lot of different things including the google maps api, if you're not interested in spending the $25 I would suggest looking into an alternative mapping api.

If on the other hand you will spend the money they've got some great tutorials laid out in the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

A Google Maps Distance Matrix API request takes the following form:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/output?parameters

If you need more information, Refer to "Distance Matrix Requests". 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#DistanceMatrixRequests

You can also use the "getDistanceMatrix" that issues a distance matrix request.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DistanceMatrixService